# Distributing Libraries

Tags: c++, distribution, libraries

How are libraries typically distributed?  Because they have to be compiled with the **same compiler** under the **same settings** as the project using it, distributing the `.dll`, `.lib`, etc. seems  impractical.  Is the source code just made available for download?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @Marcie C++.  [These are extra words so I can post a comment.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noticed, distributing libraries is impractical...  You have to care about the version of the compiler (including Service Packs), the settings used to compile, etc.  We used to have 6 different ports for each version of Visual Studio: the most important difference was the Runtime Library used (/ST, /MT or /MD).

But unless you can distribute the source code, you'll have to live with this...

Answer (score 2):

You can distribute the .dll, there's nothing wrong with that. In .NET, when you reference a library it doesn't need to be recompiled, you can just use it as is. Plenty of projects distribute their binaries but not their source.

Comment: Not according to some of the answers on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446620/returning-strings-from-dll-functions.

Comment: @Maxpm: Ah, yeah, C++ may be different. You will need different version for different platforms, as Justin said in his answer + follow recommendations you got in that SO question. In general, though, there's no requirement to distribute source with libraries.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to distribute Libraries or Applications written in C++, you will need to provide a different binary for each platform you are going to support. For example, Windows, Linux, Mac, etc. You may also need to provide different versions for each architecture, for example 32-bit Windows vs 64-bit.